# I think sometimes some answers are disappearing, is it really so? why?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes it happens that I see some answer to a post and later it is no more. eg: this one recently

[I want to rotate a parent object and see how far a certain vertex of the child object has moved](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66485/i-want-to-move-a-parent-object-and-see-the-translation-rotation-of-the-child-o)

I guess I should have enough reputation to see deleted answers, but this is not the case. Could it be a site/question "rollback", somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't have enough rep to see deleted posts. Look at the [privileges page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you need 10,000 to see deleted posts.

The question you linked to has **0** answers, deleted or live. Not sure what you saw on that one, but there have been no answers (maybe you got your links confused).

Last, nope the only rollback operation that exists is to "undo" an edit.

From the [help pages](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> **What is a rollback?**
>
> A rollback reverts a question or answer to a previous version in the edit history. The rollback action itself then appears as the most recent item in the edit history.

You would still see a post that was rolled back. Only deletion makes it so non 10K users can no longer see it.

---

Now there are plenty of "answers" that I convert to an comment; some are completely useless and I plain delete them, but I will never delete a even halfway good answer.

Comment: no I'm very sure, and is not the first time: I don't remember the question ID, but I'm sure of the content. Eg: I commented there, suggesting a possible solution, later I saw someone else answered with a similar solution, pictures, an animated gif... it was clearly the same idea as mine, but as an answer, thus I remember it very well. Im really sure. Maybe the OP has deleted the answered question, and then reposted another identical but, I commented only once... on the first one,...

Comment: and about reputation, I searched the history here and saw this, http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/366/any-way-to-view-a-deleted-answer?rq=1, so I was misleaded, perhapsl, sorry.

Comment: no, you're right I confused one question with another... sorry

Comment: I really don't know, sometimes I feel like this happens, maybe with comments, also... it should be me....

Comment: @m.ardito The meta post you linked to was correct when we were still in beta, when the site graduated all the permission levels jumped.